# Double popover window bug

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, frontend

When ever I click the button that enables the popover window, it works as it should, but when I click another button to show the popover menu for a different account, the first menu does not dissapear, and Im not sure what I need to add to my code to make that happen.

```
<td ng-class="bsPolicy.adjustBodyCell(grouplvl, '5', 'attach')" class="popover-row"
ng-if="dirvm.tabs[0].isActive">
<button class="vismaicon vismaicon-attach"
        uib-popover-template="bsPolicy.dirvmConstant.AppendicesOfGroupPopoverTemplate"
        popover-enable="false"
        popover-trigger="outsideClick" ng-click="dirvm.setCollapsedSubAppendices($event)" popover-placement="auto bottom"
        ng-if="grouplvl.accountRows.length > 0" ng-class="grouplvl.subAppendices.length > 0 ? '': 'disabled'"></button>
```

[Here is how it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Ka7.png)

Comment: what version of AngularUI-bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Im currently using version 1.3.3

Answer (score 1):

The *popover-trigger* attribute value needs to be wrapped in single quotes (as of AngularUI-Bootstrap version 2.0.0).

```
<td ng-class="bsPolicy.adjustBodyCell(grouplvl, '5', 'attach')" class="popover-row" ng-if="dirvm.tabs[0].isActive">
<button class="vismaicon vismaicon-attach"
    uib-popover-template="bsPolicy.dirvmConstant.AppendicesOfGroupPopoverTemplate"
    popover-enable="false"
    popover-trigger="'outsideClick'" ng-click="dirvm.setCollapsedSubAppendices($event)" popover-placement="auto bottom"
    ng-if="grouplvl.accountRows.length > 0"
    ng-class="grouplvl.subAppendices.length > 0 ? '': 'disabled'"></button>
```

---

Link to docs: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/popover

Comment: By singel quotes you mean wrapped in div tags? I dont really understand

Comment: Single quotes are the **'** character.See what I've done with the popover-trigger value? Instead of "outsideClick", you need to put " ' outsideClick ' ". (Spaces added for emphasis)

Comment: Didnt work. The button stopped working, and it doesnt show any error in the web console either.

Comment: And Im currently using version 1.3.3 of AngularUI-Bootstrap